# Analyzing circuit with dependent sources

Tags: circuit-analysis, network

What will be voltage **Vz** in this circuit

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fwcGSe.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I have tried to solve the equation using mesh analysis by taking **i1** and **i2** anti clockwise in upper and lower mesh respectively.

Comment: You need to post work if you want help understanding how to solve this. This isn't a do-my-homework site.

Answer (score 1):

First, see that in the upper wire you have $$I_1=-2 Vx$$ and you can write:
$$I_1 = I_2 + I_3$$, where I_2 is the current in the 2nd wire (from left to right) and I_3 is the current in the other one.
Now, you have to "decide" where the Ground is and just solve equations.

Note that V_Z has the same  voltage that the - of V_x. Using that, I got:
$$I_2 = -\frac{V_Z + V_X}{R_2}$$
$$I_3 = \frac{15V - V_Z}{R_3}$$

If you don't know V_X, you can have it using that $$2V_X = I_2 + I_3$$